# gcc: error: missing argument to '-l'

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, makefile

So I have changed my Makefile, but now when it says:

```
gcc: error: missing argument to '-l'
make: *** [nfc-emulate-forum-tag4] Error 1
```

This is the makefile in total, where I cannot even find a -l

```
pkgdatadir = $(datadir)/libnfc
pkgincludedir = $(includedir)/libnfc
pkglibdir = $(libdir)/libnfc
pkglibexecdir = $(libexecdir)/libnfc
am__cd = CDPATH="$${ZSH_VERSION+.}$(PATH_SEPARATOR)" && cd
install_sh_DATA = $(install_sh) -c -m 644
install_sh_PROGRAM = $(install_sh) -c
install_sh_SCRIPT = $(install_sh) -c
INSTALL_HEADER = $(INSTALL_DATA)
transform = $(program_transform_name)
NORMAL_INSTALL = :
PRE_INSTALL = :
POST_INSTALL = :
NORMAL_UNINSTALL = :
PRE_UNINSTALL = :
POST_UNINSTALL = :
build_triplet = armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
host_triplet = armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
bin_PROGRAMS = nfc-emulate-forum-tag4$(EXEEXT) nfc-list$(EXEEXT) \
    nfc-mfclassic$(EXEEXT) nfc-mfultralight$(EXEEXT) \
    nfc-read-forum-tag3$(EXEEXT) nfc-relay-picc$(EXEEXT) \
    nfc-scan-device$(EXEEXT)
subdir = utils
DIST_COMMON = $(dist_man_MANS) $(srcdir)/Makefile.am \
    $(srcdir)/Makefile.in
ACLOCAL_M4 = $(top_srcdir)/aclocal.m4
am__aclocal_m4_deps = $(top_srcdir)/m4/libnfc_check_libusb.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/libnfc_check_pcsc.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/libnfc_drivers.m4 $(top_srcdir)/m4/libtool.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/ltoptions.m4 $(top_srcdir)/m4/ltsugar.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/ltversion.m4 $(top_srcdir)/m4/lt~obsolete.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/readline.m4 $(top_srcdir)/configure.ac
am__configure_deps = $(am__aclocal_m4_deps) $(CONFIGURE_DEPENDENCIES) \
    $(ACLOCAL_M4)
mkinstalldirs = $(install_sh) -d
CONFIG_HEADER = $(top_builddir)/config.h
CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES =
CONFIG_CLEAN_VPATH_FILES =
LTLIBRARIES = $(noinst_LTLIBRARIES)
libnfcutils_la_LIBADD =
am_libnfcutils_la_OBJECTS = nfc-utils.lo
libnfcutils_la_OBJECTS = $(am_libnfcutils_la_OBJECTS)
AM_V_lt = $(am__v_lt_$(V))
am__v_lt_ = $(am__v_lt_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_lt_0 = --silent
am__installdirs = "$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)" "$(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)"
PROGRAMS = $(bin_PROGRAMS)
am_nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_OBJECTS = nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.$(OBJEXT)
nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_OBJECTS = $(am_nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_OBJECTS)
nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_DEPENDENCIES =  \
    $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la libnfcutils.la
am_nfc_list_OBJECTS = nfc-list.$(OBJEXT)
nfc_list_OBJECTS = $(am_nfc_list_OBJECTS)
nfc_list_DEPENDENCIES = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
    libnfcutils.la
am_nfc_mfclassic_OBJECTS = nfc-mfclassic.$(OBJEXT) mifare.$(OBJEXT)
nfc_mfclassic_OBJECTS = $(am_nfc_mfclassic_OBJECTS)
nfc_mfclassic_DEPENDENCIES = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
    libnfcutils.la
am_nfc_mfultralight_OBJECTS = nfc-mfultralight.$(OBJEXT) \
    mifare.$(OBJEXT)
nfc_mfultralight_OBJECTS = $(am_nfc_mfultralight_OBJECTS)
nfc_mfultralight_DEPENDENCIES = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la
am_nfc_read_forum_tag3_OBJECTS = nfc-read-forum-tag3.$(OBJEXT)
nfc_read_forum_tag3_OBJECTS = $(am_nfc_read_forum_tag3_OBJECTS)
nfc_read_forum_tag3_DEPENDENCIES = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
    libnfcutils.la
am_nfc_relay_picc_OBJECTS = nfc-relay-picc.$(OBJEXT)
nfc_relay_picc_OBJECTS = $(am_nfc_relay_picc_OBJECTS)
nfc_relay_picc_DEPENDENCIES = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
    libnfcutils.la
am_nfc_scan_device_OBJECTS = nfc-scan-device.$(OBJEXT)
nfc_scan_device_OBJECTS = $(am_nfc_scan_device_OBJECTS)
nfc_scan_device_DEPENDENCIES = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
    libnfcutils.la
DEFAULT_INCLUDES = -I. -I$(top_builddir)
depcomp = $(SHELL) $(top_srcdir)/depcomp
am__depfiles_maybe = depfiles
am__mv = mv -f
COMPILE = $(CC) $(DEFS) $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) $(AM_CPPFLAGS) \
    $(CPPFLAGS) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
LTCOMPILE = $(LIBTOOL) $(AM_V_lt) --tag=CC $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) \
    $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) --mode=compile $(CC) $(DEFS) \
    $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) \
    $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
AM_V_CC = $(am__v_CC_$(V))
am__v_CC_ = $(am__v_CC_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_CC_0 = @echo "  CC    " $@;
AM_V_at = $(am__v_at_$(V))
am__v_at_ = $(am__v_at_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_at_0 = @
CCLD = $(CC)
LINK = $(LIBTOOL) $(AM_V_lt) --tag=CC $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) \
    $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) --mode=link $(CCLD) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) \
    $(AM_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -I/usr/include/mysql /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16 -o $@
AM_V_CCLD = $(am__v_CCLD_$(V))
am__v_CCLD_ = $(am__v_CCLD_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_CCLD_0 = @echo "  CCLD  " $@;
AM_V_GEN = $(am__v_GEN_$(V))
am__v_GEN_ = $(am__v_GEN_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_GEN_0 = @echo "  GEN   " $@;
SOURCES = $(libnfcutils_la_SOURCES) $(nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_SOURCES) \
    $(nfc_list_SOURCES) $(nfc_mfclassic_SOURCES) \
    $(nfc_mfultralight_SOURCES) $(nfc_read_forum_tag3_SOURCES) \
    $(nfc_relay_picc_SOURCES) $(nfc_scan_device_SOURCES)
DIST_SOURCES = $(libnfcutils_la_SOURCES) \
    $(nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_SOURCES) $(nfc_list_SOURCES) \
    $(nfc_mfclassic_SOURCES) $(nfc_mfultralight_SOURCES) \
    $(nfc_read_forum_tag3_SOURCES) $(nfc_relay_picc_SOURCES) \
    $(nfc_scan_device_SOURCES)
am__vpath_adj_setup = srcdirstrip=`echo "$(srcdir)" | sed 's|.|.|g'`;
am__vpath_adj = case $$p in \
    $(srcdir)/*) f=`echo "$$p" | sed "s|^$$srcdirstrip/||"`;; \
    *) f=$$p;; \
  esac;
am__strip_dir = f=`echo $$p | sed -e 's|^.*/||'`;
am__install_max = 40
am__nobase_strip_setup = \
  srcdirstrip=`echo "$(srcdir)" | sed 's/[].[^$$\\*|]/\\\\&/g'`
am__nobase_strip = \
  for p in $$list; do echo "$$p"; done | sed -e "s|$$srcdirstrip/||"
am__nobase_list = $(am__nobase_strip_setup); \
  for p in $$list; do echo "$$p $$p"; done | \
  sed "s| $$srcdirstrip/| |;"' / .*\//!s/ .*/ ./; s,\( .*\)/[^/]*$$,\1,' | \
  $(AWK) 'BEGIN { files["."] = "" } { files[$$2] = files[$$2] " " $$1; \
    if (++n[$$2] == $(am__install_max)) \
      { print $$2, files[$$2]; n[$$2] = 0; files[$$2] = "" } } \
    END { for (dir in files) print dir, files[dir] }'
am__base_list = \
  sed '$$!N;$$!N;$$!N;$$!N;$$!N;$$!N;$$!N;s/\n/ /g' | \
  sed '$$!N;$$!N;$$!N;$$!N;s/\n/ /g'
am__uninstall_files_from_dir = { \
  test -z "$$files" \
    || { test ! -d "$$dir" && test ! -f "$$dir" && test ! -r "$$dir"; } \
    || { echo " ( cd '$$dir' && rm -f" $$files ")"; \
         $(am__cd) "$$dir" && rm -f $$files; }; \
  }
man1dir = $(mandir)/man1
NROFF = nroff
MANS = $(dist_man_MANS)
ETAGS = etags
CTAGS = ctags
DISTFILES = $(DIST_COMMON) $(DIST_SOURCES) $(TEXINFOS) $(EXTRA_DIST)
ACLOCAL = ${SHELL} /root/libnfc-1.7.0/missing --run aclocal-1.11
AMTAR = $${TAR-tar}
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY = 0
AR = ar
AUTOCONF = ${SHELL} /root/libnfc-1.7.0/missing --run autoconf
AUTOHEADER = ${SHELL} /root/libnfc-1.7.0/missing --run autoheader
AUTOMAKE = ${SHELL} /root/libnfc-1.7.0/missing --run automake-1.11
AWK = mawk
CC = gcc
CCDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -std=c99 -Du_int8_t=uint8_t -Du_int16_t=uint16_t
CPP = gcc -E
CFLAGS += -I/usr/include/mysql/ -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -Imysqlclient
CPPFLAGS = 
CUTTER = 
CUTTER_CFLAGS = 
CUTTER_LIBS = 
CYGPATH_W = echo
DEFS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DEPDIR = .deps
DLLTOOL = false
DOXYGEN = 
DRIVERS_CFLAGS =  -DDRIVER_ACR122_USB_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ACR122S_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN532_UART_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN532_SPI_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN532_I2C_ENABLED
DSYMUTIL = 
DUMPBIN = 
ECHO_C = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_T = 
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
EXEEXT = 
FGREP = /bin/grep -F
GREP = /bin/grep
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_DATA = ${INSTALL} -m 644
INSTALL_PROGRAM = ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_SCRIPT = ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM = $(install_sh) -c -s
LD = /usr/bin/ld
LDFLAGS = 
LIBNFC_CFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/libnfc -I$(top_builddir)/include -I$(top_srcdir)/include
LIBOBJS = 
LIBS = 
LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool
LIPO = 
LN_S = ln -s
LTLIBOBJS = 
MAKEINFO = ${SHELL} /root/libnfc-1.7.0/missing --run makeinfo
MANIFEST_TOOL = :
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
NM = /usr/bin/nm -B
NMEDIT = 
OBJDUMP = objdump
OBJEXT = o
OTOOL = 
OTOOL64 = 
PACKAGE = libnfc
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = nfc-tools@googlegroups.com
PACKAGE_NAME = libnfc
PACKAGE_STRING = libnfc 1.7.0
PACKAGE_TARNAME = libnfc
PACKAGE_URL = 
PACKAGE_VERSION = 1.7.0
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
PKG_CONFIG = /usr/bin/pkg-config
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR = 
PKG_CONFIG_PATH = 
PKG_CONFIG_REQUIRES =  libusb
RANLIB = ranlib
READLINE_INCLUDES = 
READLINE_LIBS = 
SED = /bin/sed
SET_MAKE = 
SHELL = /bin/bash
STRIP = strip
VERSION = 1.7.0
abs_builddir = /root/libnfc-1.7.0/utils
abs_srcdir = /root/libnfc-1.7.0/utils
abs_top_builddir = /root/libnfc-1.7.0
abs_top_srcdir = /root/libnfc-1.7.0
ac_ct_AR = ar
ac_ct_CC = gcc
ac_ct_DUMPBIN = 
am__include = include
am__leading_dot = .
am__quote = 
am__tar = $${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"
am__untar = $${TAR-tar} xf -
bindir = ${exec_prefix}/bin
build = armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
build_alias = 
build_cpu = armv6l
build_os = linux-gnueabihf
build_vendor = unknown
builddir = .
datadir = ${datarootdir}
datarootdir = ${prefix}/share
docdir = ${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}
dvidir = ${docdir}
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
host = armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
host_alias = 
host_cpu = armv6l
host_os = linux-gnueabihf
host_vendor = unknown
htmldir = ${docdir}
includedir = ${prefix}/include
infodir = ${datarootdir}/info
install_sh = ${SHELL} /root/libnfc-1.7.0/install-sh
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
libexecdir = ${exec_prefix}/libexec
libpcsclite_CFLAGS = 
libpcsclite_LIBS = 
libusb_CFLAGS =  
libusb_CONFIG = 
libusb_LIBS = -lusb  
localedir = ${datarootdir}/locale
localstatedir = ${prefix}/var
mandir = ${datarootdir}/man
mkdir_p = /bin/mkdir -p
oldincludedir = /usr/include
pdfdir = ${docdir}
prefix = /usr
program_transform_name = s,x,x,
psdir = ${docdir}
sbindir = ${exec_prefix}/sbin
sharedstatedir = ${prefix}/com
srcdir = .
sysconfdir = /etc
target_alias = 
top_build_prefix = ../
top_builddir = ..
top_srcdir = ..

# set the include path found by configure
AM_CPPFLAGS = $(all_includes) $(LIBNFC_CFLAGS)
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libnfcutils.la
libnfcutils_la_SOURCES = nfc-utils.c
nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_SOURCES = nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.c nfc-utils.h
nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
                   libnfcutils.la

nfc_list_SOURCES = nfc-list.c nfc-utils.h
nfc_list_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
         libnfcutils.la

nfc_mfclassic_SOURCES = nfc-mfclassic.c mifare.c mifare.h nfc-utils.h
nfc_mfclassic_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
            libnfcutils.la

nfc_mfultralight_SOURCES = nfc-mfultralight.c mifare.c mifare.h nfc-utils.h
nfc_mfultralight_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la
nfc_read_forum_tag3_SOURCES = nfc-read-forum-tag3.c nfc-utils.h
nfc_read_forum_tag3_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
                    libnfcutils.la

nfc_relay_picc_SOURCES = nfc-relay-picc.c nfc-utils.h
nfc_relay_picc_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
               libnfcutils.la

nfc_scan_device_SOURCES = nfc-scan-device.c nfc-utils.h
nfc_scan_device_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/libnfc/libnfc.la \
         libnfcutils.la

dist_man_MANS = \
        nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.1 \
        nfc-list.1 \
        nfc-mfclassic.1 \
        nfc-mfultralight.1 \
        nfc-read-forum-tag3.1 \
        nfc-relay-picc.1 \
        nfc-scan-device.1

EXTRA_DIST = CMakeLists.txt
all: all-am

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .lo .o .obj
$(srcdir)/Makefile.in:  $(srcdir)/Makefile.am  $(am__configure_deps)
    @for dep in $?; do \
      case '$(am__configure_deps)' in \
        *$$dep*) \
          ( cd $(top_builddir) && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) am--refresh ) \
            && { if test -f $@; then exit 0; else break; fi; }; \
          exit 1;; \
      esac; \
    done; \
    echo ' cd $(top_srcdir) && $(AUTOMAKE) --gnu utils/Makefile'; \
    $(am__cd) $(top_srcdir) && \
      $(AUTOMAKE) --gnu utils/Makefile
.PRECIOUS: Makefile
Makefile: $(srcdir)/Makefile.in $(top_builddir)/config.status
    @case '$?' in \
      *config.status*) \
        cd $(top_builddir) && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) am--refresh;; \
      *) \
        echo ' cd $(top_builddir) && $(SHELL) ./config.status $(subdir)/$@ $(am__depfiles_maybe)'; \
        cd $(top_builddir) && $(SHELL) ./config.status $(subdir)/$@ $(am__depfiles_maybe);; \
    esac;

$(top_builddir)/config.status: $(top_srcdir)/configure $(CONFIG_STATUS_DEPENDENCIES)
    cd $(top_builddir) && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) am--refresh

$(top_srcdir)/configure:  $(am__configure_deps)
    cd $(top_builddir) && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) am--refresh
$(ACLOCAL_M4):  $(am__aclocal_m4_deps)
    cd $(top_builddir) && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) am--refresh
$(am__aclocal_m4_deps):

clean-noinstLTLIBRARIES:
    -test -z "$(noinst_LTLIBRARIES)" || rm -f $(noinst_LTLIBRARIES)
    @list='$(noinst_LTLIBRARIES)'; for p in $$list; do \
      dir="`echo $$p | sed -e 's|/[^/]*$$||'`"; \
      test "$$dir" != "$$p" || dir=.; \
      echo "rm -f \"$${dir}/so_locations\""; \
      rm -f "$${dir}/so_locations"; \
    done
libnfcutils.la: $(libnfcutils_la_OBJECTS) $(libnfcutils_la_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_libnfcutils_la_DEPENDENCIES) 
    $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK)  $(libnfcutils_la_OBJECTS) $(libnfcutils_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)
install-binPROGRAMS: $(bin_PROGRAMS)
    @$(NORMAL_INSTALL)
    test -z "$(bindir)" || $(MKDIR_P) "$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)"
    @list='$(bin_PROGRAMS)'; test -n "$(bindir)" || list=; \
    for p in $$list; do echo "$$p $$p"; done | \
    sed 's/$(EXEEXT)$$//' | \
    while read p p1; do if test -f $$p || test -f $$p1; \
      then echo "$$p"; echo "$$p"; else :; fi; \
    done | \
    sed -e 'p;s,.*/,,;n;h' -e 's|.*|.|' \
        -e 'p;x;s,.*/,,;s/$(EXEEXT)$$//;$(transform);s/$$/$(EXEEXT)/' | \
    sed 'N;N;N;s,\n, ,g' | \
    $(AWK) 'BEGIN { files["."] = ""; dirs["."] = 1 } \
      { d=$$3; if (dirs[d] != 1) { print "d", d; dirs[d] = 1 } \
        if ($$2 == $$4) files[d] = files[d] " " $$1; \
        else { print "f", $$3 "/" $$4, $$1; } } \
      END { for (d in files) print "f", d, files[d] }' | \
    while read type dir files; do \
        if test "$$dir" = .; then dir=; else dir=/$$dir; fi; \
        test -z "$$files" || { \
        echo " $(INSTALL_PROGRAM_ENV) $(LIBTOOL) $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) --mode=install $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $$files '$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)$$dir'"; \
        $(INSTALL_PROGRAM_ENV) $(LIBTOOL) $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) --mode=install $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $$files "$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)$$dir" || exit $$?; \
        } \
    ; done

uninstall-binPROGRAMS:
    @$(NORMAL_UNINSTALL)
    @list='$(bin_PROGRAMS)'; test -n "$(bindir)" || list=; \
    files=`for p in $$list; do echo "$$p"; done | \
      sed -e 'h;s,^.*/,,;s/$(EXEEXT)$$//;$(transform)' \
          -e 's/$$/$(EXEEXT)/' `; \
    test -n "$$list" || exit 0; \
    echo " ( cd '$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)' && rm -f" $$files ")"; \
    cd "$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)" && rm -f $$files

clean-binPROGRAMS:
    @list='$(bin_PROGRAMS)'; test -n "$$list" || exit 0; \
    echo " rm -f" $$list; \
    rm -f $$list || exit $$?; \
    test -n "$(EXEEXT)" || exit 0; \
    list=`for p in $$list; do echo "$$p"; done | sed 's/$(EXEEXT)$$//'`; \
    echo " rm -f" $$list; \
    rm -f $$list
nfc-emulate-forum-tag4$(EXEEXT): $(nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_OBJECTS) $(nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_DEPENDENCIES) 
    @rm -f nfc-emulate-forum-tag4$(EXEEXT)
    $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK) $(nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_OBJECTS) $(nfc_emulate_forum_tag4_LDADD) $(LIBS)
nfc-list$(EXEEXT): $(nfc_list_OBJECTS) $(nfc_list_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_nfc_list_DEPENDENCIES) 
    @rm -f nfc-list$(EXEEXT)
    $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK) $(nfc_list_OBJECTS) $(nfc_list_LDADD) $(LIBS)
nfc-mfclassic$(EXEEXT): $(nfc_mfclassic_OBJECTS) $(nfc_mfclassic_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_nfc_mfclassic_DEPENDENCIES) 
    @rm -f nfc-mfclassic$(EXEEXT)
    $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK) $(nfc_mfclassic_OBJECTS) $(nfc_mfclassic_LDADD) $(LIBS)
nfc-mfultralight$(EXEEXT): $(nfc_mfultralight_OBJECTS) $(nfc_mfultralight_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_nfc_mfultralight_DEPENDENCIES) 
    @rm -f nfc-mfultralight$(EXEEXT)
    $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK) $(nfc_mfultralight_OBJECTS) $(nfc_mfultralight_LDADD) $(LIBS)
nfc-read-forum-tag3$(EXEEXT): $(nfc_read_forum_tag3_OBJECTS) $(nfc_read_forum_tag3_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_nfc_read_forum_tag3_DEPENDENCIES) 
    @rm -f nfc-read-forum-tag3$(EXEEXT)
    $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK) $(nfc_read_forum_tag3_OBJECTS) $(nfc_read_forum_tag3_LDADD) $(LIBS)
nfc-relay-picc$(EXEEXT): $(nfc_relay_picc_OBJECTS) $(nfc_relay_picc_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_nfc_relay_picc_DEPENDENCIES) 
    @rm -f nfc-relay-picc$(EXEEXT)
    $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK) $(nfc_relay_picc_OBJECTS) $(nfc_relay_picc_LDADD) $(LIBS)
nfc-scan-device$(EXEEXT): $(nfc_scan_device_OBJECTS) $(nfc_scan_device_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_nfc_scan_device_DEPENDENCIES) 
    @rm -f nfc-scan-device$(EXEEXT)
    $(AM_V_CCLD)$(LINK) $(nfc_scan_device_OBJECTS) $(nfc_scan_device_LDADD) $(LIBS)

mostlyclean-compile:
    -rm -f *.$(OBJEXT)

distclean-compile:
    -rm -f *.tab.c

include ./$(DEPDIR)/mifare.Po
include ./$(DEPDIR)/nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.Po
include ./$(DEPDIR)/nfc-list.Po
include ./$(DEPDIR)/nfc-mfclassic.Po
include ./$(DEPDIR)/nfc-mfultralight.Po
include ./$(DEPDIR)/nfc-read-forum-tag3.Po
include ./$(DEPDIR)/nfc-relay-picc.Po
include ./$(DEPDIR)/nfc-scan-device.Po
include ./$(DEPDIR)/nfc-utils.Plo

.c.o:
    $(AM_V_CC)depbase=`echo $@ | sed 's|[^/]*$$|$(DEPDIR)/&|;s|\.o$$||'`;\
    $(COMPILE) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $$depbase.Tpo -c -o $@ $< &&\
    $(am__mv) $$depbase.Tpo $$depbase.Po
#   $(AM_V_CC)source='$<' object='$@' libtool=no \
#   DEPDIR=$(DEPDIR) $(CCDEPMODE) $(depcomp) \
#   $(AM_V_CC_no)$(COMPILE) -c -o $@ $<

.c.obj:
    $(AM_V_CC)depbase=`echo $@ | sed 's|[^/]*$$|$(DEPDIR)/&|;s|\.obj$$||'`;\
    $(COMPILE) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $$depbase.Tpo -c -o $@ `$(CYGPATH_W) '$<'` &&\
    $(am__mv) $$depbase.Tpo $$depbase.Po
#   $(AM_V_CC)source='$<' object='$@' libtool=no \
#   DEPDIR=$(DEPDIR) $(CCDEPMODE) $(depcomp) \
#   $(AM_V_CC_no)$(COMPILE) -c -o $@ `$(CYGPATH_W) '$<'`

.c.lo:
    $(AM_V_CC)depbase=`echo $@ | sed 's|[^/]*$$|$(DEPDIR)/&|;s|\.lo$$||'`;\
    $(LTCOMPILE) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $$depbase.Tpo -c -o $@ $< &&\
    $(am__mv) $$depbase.Tpo $$depbase.Plo
#   $(AM_V_CC)source='$<' object='$@' libtool=yes \
#   DEPDIR=$(DEPDIR) $(CCDEPMODE) $(depcomp) \
#   $(AM_V_CC_no)$(LTCOMPILE) -c -o $@ $<

mostlyclean-libtool:
    -rm -f *.lo

clean-libtool:
    -rm -rf .libs _libs
install-man1: $(dist_man_MANS)
    @$(NORMAL_INSTALL)
    test -z "$(man1dir)" || $(MKDIR_P) "$(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)"
    @list=''; test -n "$(man1dir)" || exit 0; \
    { for i in $$list; do echo "$$i"; done; \
    l2='$(dist_man_MANS)'; for i in $$l2; do echo "$$i"; done | \
      sed -n '/\.1[a-z]*$$/p'; \
    } | while read p; do \
      if test -f $$p; then d=; else d="$(srcdir)/"; fi; \
      echo "$$d$$p"; echo "$$p"; \
    done | \
    sed -e 'n;s,.*/,,;p;h;s,.*\.,,;s,^[^1][0-9a-z]*$$,1,;x' \
          -e 's,\.[0-9a-z]*$$,,;$(transform);G;s,\n,.,' | \
    sed 'N;N;s,\n, ,g' | { \
    list=; while read file base inst; do \
      if test "$$base" = "$$inst"; then list="$$list $$file"; else \
        echo " $(INSTALL_DATA) '$$file' '$(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)/$$inst'"; \
        $(INSTALL_DATA) "$$file" "$(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)/$$inst" || exit $$?; \
      fi; \
    done; \
    for i in $$list; do echo "$$i"; done | $(am__base_list) | \
    while read files; do \
      test -z "$$files" || { \
        echo " $(INSTALL_DATA) $$files '$(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)'"; \
        $(INSTALL_DATA) $$files "$(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)" || exit $$?; }; \
    done; }

uninstall-man1:
    @$(NORMAL_UNINSTALL)
    @list=''; test -n "$(man1dir)" || exit 0; \
    files=`{ for i in $$list; do echo "$$i"; done; \
    l2='$(dist_man_MANS)'; for i in $$l2; do echo "$$i"; done | \
      sed -n '/\.1[a-z]*$$/p'; \
    } | sed -e 's,.*/,,;h;s,.*\.,,;s,^[^1][0-9a-z]*$$,1,;x' \
          -e 's,\.[0-9a-z]*$$,,;$(transform);G;s,\n,.,'`; \
    dir='$(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)'; $(am__uninstall_files_from_dir)

ID: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES) $(LISP) $(TAGS_FILES)
    list='$(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) $(LISP) $(TAGS_FILES)'; \
    unique=`for i in $$list; do \
        if test -f "$$i"; then echo $$i; else echo $(srcdir)/$$i; fi; \
      done | \
      $(AWK) '{ files[$$0] = 1; nonempty = 1; } \
          END { if (nonempty) { for (i in files) print i; }; }'`; \
    mkid -fID $$unique
tags: TAGS

TAGS:  $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)  $(TAGS_DEPENDENCIES) \
        $(TAGS_FILES) $(LISP)
    set x; \
    here=`pwd`; \
    list='$(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)  $(LISP) $(TAGS_FILES)'; \
    unique=`for i in $$list; do \
        if test -f "$$i"; then echo $$i; else echo $(srcdir)/$$i; fi; \
      done | \
      $(AWK) '{ files[$$0] = 1; nonempty = 1; } \
          END { if (nonempty) { for (i in files) print i; }; }'`; \
    shift; \
    if test -z "$(ETAGS_ARGS)$$*$$unique"; then :; else \
      test -n "$$unique" || unique=$$empty_fix; \
      if test $$# -gt 0; then \
        $(ETAGS) $(ETAGSFLAGS) $(AM_ETAGSFLAGS) $(ETAGS_ARGS) \
          "$$@" $$unique; \
      else \
        $(ETAGS) $(ETAGSFLAGS) $(AM_ETAGSFLAGS) $(ETAGS_ARGS) \
          $$unique; \
      fi; \
    fi
ctags: CTAGS
CTAGS:  $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)  $(TAGS_DEPENDENCIES) \
        $(TAGS_FILES) $(LISP)
    list='$(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)  $(LISP) $(TAGS_FILES)'; \
    unique=`for i in $$list; do \
        if test -f "$$i"; then echo $$i; else echo $(srcdir)/$$i; fi; \
      done | \
      $(AWK) '{ files[$$0] = 1; nonempty = 1; } \
          END { if (nonempty) { for (i in files) print i; }; }'`; \
    test -z "$(CTAGS_ARGS)$$unique" \
      || $(CTAGS) $(CTAGSFLAGS) $(AM_CTAGSFLAGS) $(CTAGS_ARGS) \
         $$unique

GTAGS:
    here=`$(am__cd) $(top_builddir) && pwd` \
      && $(am__cd) $(top_srcdir) \
      && gtags -i $(GTAGS_ARGS) "$$here"

distclean-tags:
    -rm -f TAGS ID GTAGS GRTAGS GSYMS GPATH tags

distdir: $(DISTFILES)
    @list='$(MANS)'; if test -n "$$list"; then \
      list=`for p in $$list; do \
        if test -f $$p; then d=; else d="$(srcdir)/"; fi; \
        if test -f "$$d$$p"; then echo "$$d$$p"; else :; fi; done`; \
      if test -n "$$list" && \
        grep 'ab help2man is required to generate this page' $$list >/dev/null; then \
        echo "error: found man pages containing the \`missing help2man' replacement text:" >&2; \
        grep -l 'ab help2man is required to generate this page' $$list | sed 's/^/         /' >&2; \
        echo "       to fix them, install help2man, remove and regenerate the man pages;" >&2; \
        echo "       typically \`make maintainer-clean' will remove them" >&2; \
        exit 1; \
      else :; fi; \
    else :; fi
    @srcdirstrip=`echo "$(srcdir)" | sed 's/[].[^$$\\*]/\\\\&/g'`; \
    topsrcdirstrip=`echo "$(top_srcdir)" | sed 's/[].[^$$\\*]/\\\\&/g'`; \
    list='$(DISTFILES)'; \
      dist_files=`for file in $$list; do echo $$file; done | \
      sed -e "s|^$$srcdirstrip/||;t" \
          -e "s|^$$topsrcdirstrip/|$(top_builddir)/|;t"`; \
    case $$dist_files in \
      */*) $(MKDIR_P) `echo "$$dist_files" | \
               sed '/\//!d;s|^|$(distdir)/|;s,/[^/]*$$,,' | \
               sort -u` ;; \
    esac; \
    for file in $$dist_files; do \
      if test -f $$file || test -d $$file; then d=.; else d=$(srcdir); fi; \
      if test -d $$d/$$file; then \
        dir=`echo "/$$file" | sed -e 's,/[^/]*$$,,'`; \
        if test -d "$(distdir)/$$file"; then \
          find "$(distdir)/$$file" -type d ! -perm -700 -exec chmod u+rwx {} \;; \
        fi; \
        if test -d $(srcdir)/$$file && test $$d != $(srcdir); then \
          cp -fpR $(srcdir)/$$file "$(distdir)$$dir" || exit 1; \
          find "$(distdir)/$$file" -type d ! -perm -700 -exec chmod u+rwx {} \;; \
        fi; \
        cp -fpR $$d/$$file "$(distdir)$$dir" || exit 1; \
      else \
        test -f "$(distdir)/$$file" \
        || cp -p $$d/$$file "$(distdir)/$$file" \
        || exit 1; \
      fi; \
    done
check-am: all-am
check: check-am
all-am: Makefile $(LTLIBRARIES) $(PROGRAMS) $(MANS)
installdirs:
    for dir in "$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)" "$(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)"; do \
      test -z "$$dir" || $(MKDIR_P) "$$dir"; \
    done
install: install-am
install-exec: install-exec-am
install-data: install-data-am
uninstall: uninstall-am

install-am: all-am
    @$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) install-exec-am install-data-am

installcheck: installcheck-am
install-strip:
    if test -z '$(STRIP)'; then \
      $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) INSTALL_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" \
        install_sh_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" INSTALL_STRIP_FLAG=-s \
          install; \
    else \
      $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) INSTALL_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" \
        install_sh_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" INSTALL_STRIP_FLAG=-s \
        "INSTALL_PROGRAM_ENV=STRIPPROG='$(STRIP)'" install; \
    fi
mostlyclean-generic:

clean-generic:

distclean-generic:
    -test -z "$(CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES)" || rm -f $(CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES)
    -test . = "$(srcdir)" || test -z "$(CONFIG_CLEAN_VPATH_FILES)" || rm -f $(CONFIG_CLEAN_VPATH_FILES)

maintainer-clean-generic:
    @echo "This command is intended for maintainers to use"
    @echo "it deletes files that may require special tools to rebuild."
clean: clean-am

clean-am: clean-binPROGRAMS clean-generic clean-libtool \
    clean-noinstLTLIBRARIES mostlyclean-am

distclean: distclean-am
    -rm -rf ./$(DEPDIR)
    -rm -f Makefile
distclean-am: clean-am distclean-compile distclean-generic \
    distclean-tags

dvi: dvi-am

dvi-am:
```

I'va searched for the directory /usr/lib/mysql/ but I don't have it.

I have not managed to find the solution to this error on internet, so maybe one of you have any idea or just some info to find it out myself.

Comment: Well, it _is_ important the "makefile part"..

Comment: @KirilKirov The problem is I have no idea on which row the error is.. I tried undo my changes but still says this. Any tip where I could search?

Comment: Can't you post the whole `Makefile`? For a hint, see @unwind 's answer below.

Comment: That line is clearly not the problem as it does not include the `-l` flag. You need to find, as @unwind indicates in his answer, the line in your makefile where you have a bare `-l` with no following library name. Presumably it will be in one of the lines you just edited.

Comment: First you said the makefile part was unimportant, now you're showing us one line that you suspect is involved. Get back to us when you're ready to show the whole (preferably [minimal](http://sscce.org)) makefile and tell us what change you made *that precipitated this error*.

Comment: @KirilKirov Well, the makefile has 750 rows so I don't think that's appropriate. Give me a minute

Comment: gmake has a couple of options that may be useful.  First you can get it to print what it "would have done" with -n.  And then there is the somewhat verbose -d option, which prints everything make does.  You need to look for the actual 'gcc' command with the bad option in it, and then track down where in the makefile it came from.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Kiick Thank you very much, it made it easier and solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's some error in your Makefile.

You are giving the compiler the option `-l` which is used to include a library, but then you don't give it the expected name of the library. [See the GCC manual for details on this option and its usage](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Libraries-1076).

Typically the option is used like this:

```
gcc -o myprog myproc.c -lm
```

To include the library called "libm.a", for instance.